# How to implement a script interpreter in shell on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, shell, shebang

I'm trying to implement, in shell, a script interpreter that I can use in a shebang line. For example, here is my interpreter and a test script using that interpreter:

```
-----
$ cat interp
#! /usr/bin/env bash

printf "interp called with args: %s\n" "$*"

-----
$ cat test
#! ./interp

printf "test script!\n"
```

When I run `./test` on a Linux system, `interp` is called with the arguments that I expect:

```
$ ./test -a
interp called with args: ./test -a
```

But when I do the same on Mac OS X 10.8.4, I get the following result:

```
$ ./test -a
test script!
```

The contents of the `test` script are being executed by bash, rather than the `interp` script being executed with the `test` file as the first argument.

Am I doing this correctly and such a thing simply won't work on Mac OS X?  Or is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: Works as expected with zsh on OSX 10.6.8, but not with the macports bash.

Comment: Mac OS X requires the program named in the shebang to be a binary executable, not a script, AFAICR.  The workaround anubhava suggests runs `/usr/bin/env` (a binary executable) and requests it to run your script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is a way to make it work on OSX, which is same as what you did in your first script i.e. by using `/usr/bin/env`.

Have `./test` as:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ./interp

printf "test script!\n"
```

Comment: This does work, than you.  Any idea why my first attempt did not work? (It also fails if I use absolute path rather than #! ./interp)

Comment: Yes it doesn't work with full path to `interp` also on OSX. I am still researching why OSX needs `/usr/bin/env` but Linux doesn't. I will update once I find something.

Answer (score -1):

OS X is built on top of UNIX. The application Terminal takes you from the outer world of OS X to the inner world of UNIX. Terminal is located in the Utilities folder inside the Applications folder. To open Terminal, double-click the Terminal icon, and you see a window like the one shown in the figure.